# Numpy Array stack from Matplotlib images only works when showing each individual plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, astropy, astronomy

I'm stacking three-band rgb images by plotting each band in matplotlib and then stacking using numpy arrays. Thing is, it only works if I show each plotted band, otherwise I get a small color image overlayed on one large grey one. My full code is a little too long but here's the final stacking and plotting

```
    img1 = Image.open(dir_input+'/redband.png')
    img2 = Image.open(dir_input+'/greenband.png')
    img3 = Image.open(dir_input+'/blueband.png')
    data = np.array(img1, dtype='uint8')
    data2 = np.array(img2, dtype='uint8')
    data3 = np.array(img3, dtype='uint8')
    #Converts images to single channel
    data = data[:,:,0]
    data2 = data2[:,:,0]
    data3 = data3[:,:,0]

    rgb = np.dstack((data,data2,data3)) #Stack the three arrays
    plt.imshow(rgb, cmap = 'hsv') #Shows stacked image and applies HSV colormap
    #Removes white space and axes
    final_file = 'Final_{}'.format(objects)
    plt.title(objects)
    plt.gca().set_axis_off()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)
    plt.margins(0,0)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.savefig(dir_input+'/'+final_file, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0) #Saves final image in inputted directory
```

Images in question:

Wrong
[image: Wrong]

Right

[image: Right]

Comment: Without access to the original images, I fear that there is no way to confirm this (help you). I tried the same code with different png images (split the example image [from here](http://www.opticscentral.com.au/blog/narrowband-part-2-types-filters-work/) ) and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @Asmus it seems it has something to do with the plot formatting with the whitespace when stacking, removing it fixed. Unsure why this conflicted though